# Proguard missing class R$raw not resolved by -keep class

Tags: android, proguard, android-r8

I'm trying to build my app that uses `R.raw.resource_name`, but i get the following error:

```
Missing class my.package.name.R$raw (referenced from: void my.package.name.ClassName.<init>(android.content.Context, boolean, java.util.List))
```

Adding this line to proguard-rules.pro doesn't resolve the error:

```
-keep class my.package.name.R$raw
```

-dontwarn with the same class allows to build the app, but fails in runtime:

```
-dontwarn my.package.name.R$raw
```

What is the proper way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the issue, when renaming a raw file without extension Android Studio adds a dot in the end. So the issue was that i had `tmp.` file inistead of `tmp`. This was not detected in the syntax highlighting, but failed the buid. Renaming the file helped.

Answer (score 1):

I validated your problem in Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 2.

I have filed
https://issuetracker.google.com/326180138
to track this in studio.

Studio should not rename the file tmp. and aapt2 should (potentially) not just ignore the file